# If $f$ is bijective and continuous, and $\underset{||x||_{\infty} \rightarrow +\infty}{||f(x)||_{ \infty}}= + \infty$ then $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f:(\mathbb{R}^d, ||\cdot||_{\infty}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^d, ||\cdot||_{\infty})$, bijective and continuous. Suppose that $$\underset{||x||_{\infty} \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim ||f(x)||_{ \infty}}= + \infty$$ Show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

So I figured the best way to do it was to take a sequence $(y_n)$ that converges to $y$ and show that $f^{-1}(y_n)$ converges to $f^{-1}(y)$. As $f$ is bijective, then there exists $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n)=(y_n)$ and there exists $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. So all is left to do is to show that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.

I believe it would be the wisest to try to find some kind of inequality such that $||x_n - x||_{\infty}$ converges to $0$. But I am rather well stuck. Any hint and help is welcome!

Comment: Since $(y_n)$ is bounded, the condition gives you that $(x_n)$ is bounded. Can you see how to proceed?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for the help, but I don't really see how to use it, can you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since convergent sequences are bounded, $(y_n)$ is bounded. The condition

$$\lim_{\lVert x\rVert_{\infty} \to +\infty} \lVert f(x)\rVert_{\infty} = +\infty$$

implies that the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded. For if it had a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\lVert x_{n_k}\rVert_{\infty} \to +\infty$, we'd have $\lVert y_{n_k}\rVert_{\infty} \to +\infty$ for the corresponding subsequence of $(y_n)$.

So, by the Bolzano-Weierstraß theorem, every subsequence of $(x_n)$ has a convergent sub-subsequence. If $(x_n)$ were not convergent to $x$, there'd be an $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\lVert x_{n_k} - x\rVert_{\infty} \geqslant \varepsilon_0$ for all $k$. By the preceding remark, we may assume that $(x_{n_k})$ converges, say to $\xi$. Then on the one hand, we have

$$f(\xi) = f\Bigl(\lim_{k\to \infty} x_{n_k}\Bigr) = \lim_{k\to \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = \lim_{k\to \infty} y_{n_k} = y$$

by the continuity of $f$, and on the other hand $\lVert \xi - x\rVert_{\infty} \geqslant \varepsilon$, so in particular $\xi \neq x$ by the choice of the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. But then $f(\xi) = f(x)$ contradicts the injectivity of $f$. Hence it follows that $x_n \to x$, which is the continuity of $f^{-1}$ at $y$. Since that works for arbitrary $y$, we have the global continuity of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, very good answer!